# How to include template content of the current route into the main layout when performing Ajax or curl request to specific Angular Page

Tags: ajax, angularjs, curl

When making a request from curl to a AngularJS page, instead of loading the entire content, only the main layout (index.html) is loaded. The routing was done using $routeProvider.

e.g.:

```
curl -verbose http://host/students
```

The content retrieved contains the index.html but the

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

is empty.
The page is loaded correctly in the browser, rendering the template corresponding to the current route

How can one retrieve the html including the rendered template using a http client like curl?